# How to get OneLogin policy name assigned to a group

Tags: api, onelogin

Trying to get information about the policy name assigned to a group but calling the api/1/groups endpoint (with or without an id) is returning the id and name of the group only.

How can I find out which policy ist assigned to a group and how can I get the list of all currently defined policies?

thanks & regards
Tino

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot. Unfortunately Onelogin does not expose user security policy information through any APIs.